# In Docker, if the manager in a single-manager swarm fails, your services continue to run?

Tags: docker

According to [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/nodes) it states:

> “For testing purposes it is OK to run a swarm with a single manager. If the manager in a single-manager swarm fails, your services continue to run, but you need to create a new cluster to recover.”

If manager is down, how can the service still run?

Answer (score 0):

The swarm manager is responsible for scheduling changes in the cluster. While the manager is down, you cannot make changes to services running in the cluster, nor will you be able to reschedule tasks on another node should a worker fail. However, tasks already running on workers will continue to run.